# Calling variables in a for loop to make a list (using np.sin/np.cos)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am attempting to create a function that outputs this:

`[1,cos(t),sin(t),cos(2*t),sin(2*t), ... ,cos(n*t),sin(n*t)]`

called `row_func` that accepts t and n as input.

This is my code so far:

```
def row_func(t,n):
 L=0
 g=np.cos()
 h=np.sin()
 L=[f(k) for k in range(n,t) for f in [g,h]]
 L.insert(0,1)
 return L
```

When I use input like: `row_func(1,5)`, for example, it throws an error saying invalid number of arguments.

I also know that the n being where it is won't accomplish what the example has but I don't know how else to incorporate it.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: There should not be parentheses on the numpy functions. You are not calling them then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple loop can do the job:

```
import math

def row_func(t, n):
    out = [1]
    for k in range(n + 1):
        out.append(math.cos(k * t))
        out.append(math.sin(k * t))

    return out
```

Comment: Yet I did not really get what to do at the zero index... (cos(0) = 1, sin(0) = 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [194]: row_func(1,5)                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-a47e3d49d002> in <module>
----> 1 row_func(1,5)

<ipython-input-193-d278f021d727> in row_func(t, n)
      1 def row_func(t,n):
      2  L=0
----> 3  g=np.cos()
      4  h=np.sin()
      5  L=[f(k) for k in range(n,t) for f in [g,h]]

ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

Notice that 2nd -->?  It tells us the problem is with that `np.cos()` expression.  So we need to review the docs for `np.cos`, right?

Drop the (), and it runs:

```
In [196]: def row_func(t,n): 
     ...:  L=0 
     ...:  g=np.cos 
     ...:  h=np.sin 
     ...:  L=[f(k) for k in range(n,t) for f in [g,h]] 
     ...:  L.insert(0,1) 
     ...:  return L 
     ...:                                                                       
In [197]:                                                                       
In [197]: row_func(1,5)                                                         
Out[197]: [1]
```

Lets clean up the ranges:

```
In [200]: def row_func(t,n): 
     ...:  g=np.cos 
     ...:  h=np.sin 
     ...:  L=[f(k) for k in range(t,n) for f in [g,h]] 
     ...:  return L 
     ...:   
     ...:                                                                       
In [201]: row_func(1,5)                                                         
Out[201]: 
[0.5403023058681398,
 0.8414709848078965,
 -0.4161468365471424,
 0.9092974268256817,
 -0.9899924966004454,
 0.1411200080598672,
 -0.6536436208636119,
 -0.7568024953079282]
```

`np.cos` works with an array, so we can remove the inner most iteration, replacing that with `arange`:

```
In [202]: def row_func(t,n): 
     ...:  g=np.cos 
     ...:  h=np.sin 
     ...:  L=[f(np.arange(t,n)) for f in [g,h]] 
     ...:  return L 
     ...:                                                                       
In [203]: row_func(1,5)                                                         
Out[203]: 
[array([ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 , -0.65364362]),
 array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 ])]
```

Or perhaps more compactly:

```
In [207]: x = np.arange(1,5)                                                    
In [208]: [np.cos(x), np.sin(x)]                                                
Out[208]: 
[array([ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 , -0.65364362]),
 array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 ])]
```